# "not a valid xpath expression" selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, syntax

I am trying to select an element in my web page with the xpath expression.

This is the essential parts of the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
...

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
...

xpath = "//select[@onchange='onCodeChanged('14', this);']/option[text()='CPT 99429']"
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
e.click()
```

Part of page source i'm trying to select:

```
<select class="form-control select dictionary-entry" onchange="onCodeChanged('14', this);">
   <option value="WC_CARE:14"></option>
   <option value="CPT:99429">CPT 99429</option>
   <option value="HCPCS:G0402">HCPCS G0402</option>
   ....
</select>
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//select[@onchange='onCodeChanged('14', this);']/option[text()='CPT 99429']' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

I have a feeling this has something to do with having the quotation marks or the ; symbol, as I've used this same method of selecting elements in the web page successfully, but now getting this error.

Comment: Try `xpath = """//select[@onchange="onCodeChanged('14', this);"]/option[text()='CPT 99429']"""`

Comment: great! thank you that worked

Comment: @Andersson : you might wanna add this comment as an answer , zonzon510 would accept it . 
 so this question would be closed.